# Чистка Windows 10

Tags: windows

Что можно удалить в Windows 10 без ущерба ее работоспособности.

1. Какие папки с установочными файлами, можно удалять?
   Я чистил такие:

   - Temp;
   - SoftwareDistribution;
   - Temporary Internet Files;
   - Downloaded Program Files;
   - History;
   - Recent;
   - Prefetch;
   - Cookies;

   Просто Windows 10, после каждого обновления безобожно забирает место
   на жестком диске. Постоянно, что докачивает. Отключил, также режим
   гибернации, освободилось ещё пару гигабайтов.
2. Может, можно что-то в ней отключить дополнительно, кроме обновления системы и режима гибернации?
3. Вопрос, можно описание, что за папки и для чего они нужны?
   Windows.~BT;
   System.sav;
   Windows.old.

Comment: Все это (включая Windows.old) отлично вычищает стандартный Disk Cleanup :)

Comment: Windows.old точно можно удалять, если не планируется восстановление системы до состояния на момент обновления.

Answer (score 1):

Я не думаю что чистка файлов вручную в данном случае - решение проблемы, тк это проблема винды, а чистка файлов - только временное решение.
В windows 10 предусмотрена функция *самоочистки*.
Это делается так:

1. Делаете бэкап нужной информации.
2. Заходите в настройки > безопасность > восстановление.
3. Жмёте начать и делаете всё по инструкции.